# Is it a legal thing to do to sell fabricated accounts of your game?

Tags: mmo, legal

For example, say I create an online mass multiplayer game with in-game purchasing system and with randomness factors as well (the point is that game accounts have actual value and there is a somehow proportional relationship with playing time plus the luck of the player and the account's value) and the game appears to become popular.

Is it legal to, for example, insert cheated accounts into the database (without even spend a second of legitimate playing) and sell those accounts with extremely high price?

Comment: How does this differ in any way from selling e.g. powerful items via microtransactions, or level boosts to your character? (it doesn't). Although some countries might have laws against gambling where selling anything that has a random chance might be considered illegal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's nothing preventing you from selling anything you make in your own game (within reason). This is known as a [pay-to-win](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pay-to-win&amp=true&defid=5577668) scenario, which many players often complain about.

Comment: This isn't universally true, if you're going to have real world monetary transactions involved in your game you should consult an attorney in your jurisdiction prior to doing anything you might later regret. Passing an idea by a lawyer may seem expensive but litigation is much more so.

Comment: Yes, that's true I suppose. What I really meant to say was that if you already have a system for selling things in your game, there's no reason you have to limit what goes into the storefront (within reason).

Comment: That's actually exactly what I'm getting at. Price range, type of items, how it can be purchased, how it affects the game for the purchasing player, how it affects the game for other players, and if it involves random chance, can it be sold or traded in game, can it be sold and traded in real life? All of those elements can lead to very different outcomes if someone takes legal action against your game and tries to argue any one of the possible cases that your game violated regulations in their jurisdiction that caused them perceived damages. This is typically a mess meant for an attorney.